# Using @Input between parent and child component via routing module in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular13, angular-input

This is parent component :

parent.component.ts ==>

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: '<div>
                 <h1>I am the parent</h1>
                 <p>{{textForChild}}</p>
                </div>'
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() textForChild!: string;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void { }

}
```

And this is the app-routing.module.ts ==>

```
{
    path: '',
    component: ParentComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'children-url',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('@modules/child.module').then((m) => m.ChildModule),
      }
    ],
  },
```

\\\\\\\\\\\\\

And This is Child Component :

child.module.ts ==>

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':id',
    component: ChildComponent,
  },
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ChildComponent],
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
})
```

The question is, 
if I code in child.component.html, how to fill the **textForChild** above?

Answer (score 1):

One way is injecting `ParentComponent` inside `ChildComponent` constructor.

```ts
@Component({...})
class ChildComponent {

   constructor(parent:ParentComponent) {
   // access properties of parent here
   parent.textForChild
   }
}
```

Note:
This approach has a very big disadvantage i.e. Now you child component can only used under ParentComponent

Comment: Thank you.. I see it works.. But do you have any suggest to another way?